# Why NgModelController.$modelValue != $parse(attrs.ngModel)(scope)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Code: http://plnkr.co/edit/xPZM5E7tjYqlt5NIabIu?p=preview **line-no:17**

In this code if I use `ctrl.$modelValue = nVal;` instead of                  `$parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, nVal);` then it does not work. Can you please point-out the reason?

```
angModule.directive('moChangeProxy', function ($parse) {
    return {
        require:'^ngModel',
        restrict:'A',
        link:function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            var proxyExp = attrs.moChangeProxy;            
            scope.$watch(proxyExp, function (nVal) {
                if (nVal != ctrl.$modelValue) {
                    //ctrl.$modelValue = nVal;  // This does not work                  
                    $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, nVal); // This works well
                }
            });
            elm.bind('blur', function () {
                var proxyVal = scope.$eval(proxyExp);
                if(ctrl.$modelValue != proxyVal) {
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        $parse(proxyExp).assign(scope, ctrl.$modelValue);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess that by "does not work" you mean that when the change occurs, it does not run stuff like all the $formatters and update the $viewValue?

If so, this is because ngModelController watches the "model expression" for changes rather than watching its own $modelValue.

See these lines: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1046-L1065

If you update the model then the watch is triggered and all the machinery gets put into action.  If you $modelValue, the ngModelController is not aware of the change.

Comment: I think directly changing value through ctrl.$modelValueis abuse of controller 's private variable. :)

Comment: I think angular should provide ngModelController.setModelValue() function.

Comment: Doesn't $setViewValue() do what you want?  See also http://docs.angularjs.org/#comment-694294152

Comment: @SunnyShah: seems like $modelValue is a public variable - documented in NgModelController API. If it were meant to be private, would it be better to provide only a $getModelValue() method?